# Got too many errors in server chat.py in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

It seems i have 2 errors, 1st is that cannot concatenate str and bytes, 2nd is that that the connection was closed by the remote host. Wanna help.

I want that this sends a message to all the clients that this person has left the chat, instead of that it is giving the 2nd answer.

Server_chat.py

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def accept_incoming_connections():
    """Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
        print("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
        client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave! Now type your name and press enter!", "utf8"))
        addresses[client] = client_address
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()


def handle_client(client):  # Takes client socket as argument.
    """Handles a single client connection."""

    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % name
    client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
    msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
    broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    clients[client] = name

    while True:
        msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode('utf8')
        if msg != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
            broadcast(msg, name+": ")
        else:
            client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
            client.close()
            del clients[client]
            broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % name, "utf8"))
            break


def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):

    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)

        
clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

client_chat.py

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import tkinter


def receive():
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break


def send(event=None):  # event is passed by binders.
    """Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = my_msg.get()
    my_msg.set("")  # Clears input field.
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        top.quit()


def on_closing(event=None):
    """This function is to be called when the window is closed."""
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chatter")

messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()  # For the messages to be sent.
my_msg.set("Type your messages here.")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)  # To navigate through past messages.
# Following will contain the messages.
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=50, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

#----Now comes the sockets part----
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 33000
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Error

```
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
== RESTART: C:\Users\arun.kumar2\Documents\python\chatting app\server_chat.py ==
Waiting for connection...
127.0.0.1:59150 has connected.
127.0.0.1:59176 has connected.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arun.kumar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\arun.kumar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arun.kumar2\Documents\python\chatting app\server_chat.py", line 28, in handle_client
    broadcast(msg, name+": ")
  File "C:\Users\arun.kumar2\Documents\python\chatting app\server_chat.py", line 40, in broadcast
    sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arun.kumar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\arun.kumar2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arun.kumar2\Documents\python\chatting app\server_chat.py", line 26, in handle_client
    msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode('utf8')
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: *"I am not able to post the question due to less description..."* - instead of filling the question with junk clearly describe what your expectation is and what you get instead. Also just dump code but create a __minimal__ example which shows your problem.

Comment: ok, sorry for that. I want to send automatically a message to all the clients that someone has left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first error said, you cannot concat `str` (`msg`) and `bytes`, so use:

```py
sock.send(bytes(prefix+msg, "utf8"))
```

Also you should not call `bytes(...)` on the argument of `broadcast()` like below:

```
broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
```

Since you have called `bytes(...)` inside `broadcast()`. Use below instead:

```
broadcast(msg)
```

For the second error, it is because the connection to client is lost but the server is still trying to read from client.  You should use `try/except` to catch the connection lost.

Below is the modified `handle_client()` and `broadcast()`:

```
def handle_client(client):  # Takes client socket as argument.
    """Handles a single client connection."""

    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % name
    client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
    msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
    broadcast(msg) ###
    clients[client] = name

    while True:
        try:
            msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode('utf8')
            if msg != "{quit}": ###
                broadcast(msg, name+": ")
            else:
                client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
                break
        except (ConnectionResetError, ConnectionAbortedError):
            break

    client.close()
    del clients[client]
    broadcast("%s has left the chat." % name) ###
    print(name, "disconnected")

def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix+msg, "utf8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Error is at server_chat.py at line 40`

You can't contact string with bytes type so you have to keep them both same type or chnage type of one of them.

```
def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix+msg, "utf8"))
```

Comment: @ParvanshuSharma You can say thanks by marking ans correct :)